# Inequality for expected value of X and $X^{-1}$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expected-value

I've got the following problem: we are given a random variable X such that $0 < a \leq X \leq b$ and we need to estimate $(\mathbb{E}X)\mathbb{E}(X^{-1})$ from above. I suggest that 
$$(\mathbb{E}X)\mathbb{E}(X^{-1}) \leq \frac12\left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}\right)$$
I just guessed it but I'm quite sure that's true because I can prove it if $X$ can be only $c_1$ and $c_2$ with probabilities $p$ and $(1 - p)$ correspondingly. I'll be glad for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mu$ is the measure correponding to the density of $X$, then we can write both
\begin{align*}
(\Bbb EX)(\Bbb EX^{-1}) &= \int_a^b t\,d\mu(t) \int_a^b \frac1u\,d\mu(u) \\
(\Bbb EX)(\Bbb EX^{-1}) &= \int_a^b u\,d\mu(u) \int_a^b \frac1t\,d\mu(t);
\end{align*}
adding these together yields
$$
2 (\Bbb EX)(\Bbb EX^{-1}) = \int_a^b \int_a^b \bigg( \frac tu+\frac ut \bigg) \,d\mu(u)\,d\mu(t).
$$
The fact that $g(y)=y+\frac1y$ is an increasing function for $y\ge1$ implies in particular that $\frac tu+\frac ut \le \frac ab+\frac ba$ when $a\le t\le b$ and $a\le u\le b$; therefore
$$
2 (\Bbb EX)(\Bbb EX^{-1}) \le \bigg( \frac ab+\frac ba \bigg) \int_a^b \int_a^b \,d\mu(u)\,d\mu(t) = \frac ab+\frac ba.
$$

Comment: Oh, that's my fault. I forgot to add that $X$ is discrete, but I think this proof can be transformed to a discrete variant. Thank you.

Comment: Fair enough—but also, $\mu$ can be a singular/atomic measure, so this proof even works as is :)